# Reading data into a Java applet through PHP

Tags: java, php, applet

I have written a Java applet that manages persistent data by storing the most recent text field entry in a text file formatted as follows:

```
Key: day; Value: 1  
Key: month; Value: 1  
Key: year; Value: 1900
```

(In this case, this data represents the date January 1, 1900.) I have the writing to file ability complete, and it is accomplished by opening a PHP file through the Java applet and sending the text values to the PHP file, which then writes to file.

However, I am now trying to figure out how to read from this text file and restore the data into the Java applet, but I have no idea what to do as I have very little experience with PHP. Is there some way to use PHP to read from the text file to the applet?

Comment: Try posting the code to the applet or make the question more specific. Also explain what you've tried so far and the errors you're getting.

Comment: If the 'file' is accessible with HTTP requests, you could request the file directly from the Java Applet. Be careful though, somebody might send something else than you expect to the file (because the PHP writer is accessible over HTTP).

Comment: I'll post the code. I haven't tried anything yet, since I have no idea where to start. I am wondering if PHP has an ability to read from a file similar to writing to the file.  EDIT: I realized that my code is on my desktop, while I'm on my laptop in class right now. I will post the code once I get home!

Comment: When you say "opening a PHP file through the Java applet" do you mean invoking PHP script through the java applet, which than writes into a file?

Comment: Exactly! That's how I implemented the writing... open a PHP connection within the applet, then send the applet data (day, month, year) to the PHP script, which then writes the text file in the above format.

Comment: PHP does have ability to read from a file it's the same as write here is a link to a small tutorial [http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileread.php](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileread.php). You can just read into a variable and return it to your applet.